# How can I track the progress of a booster or publicist badge?

Tags: support, badges

I've shared a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15544310/1341006) on SO, I already got anouncer badge. Now, I want to check the progress of booster or publicist badge OR I want to know the no of times the shared link is opened by the different IP's. Is there any way to track that?

Comment: Not possible currently, as I guess you want such a thing I voted to close as dupe of existing request.